# Excel formula to part match and return the highest value

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

Helo,

I need a formula to input the values on "input" column. Basically where is just the name of the country to put that value and where is the name of the country with number to give me the highest result between those. For example if country is "Afghanistan Mob" in the input column should be the highest value from "Afghanistan 1....Afghanistan 5". I did it manually and the results are in the "manual input" column.
I tried maxifs, index match with if search, vlookup but seems to miss something!

I can use maxifs as the excel is an older version!!
Thanks

[image: image here]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to re-write your logic, please confirm if that applies:

If the last three characters of the country in column D are "Mob", then sum all data with the country name followed by a dash and a number. If the country name does not end with "Mob", then just lookup that country value.

```
=IF(RIGHT(D2,4)=" Mob",SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,LEFT(D2,FIND(" Mob",D2)-1)&"-*"),SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2))
```

**Edit:** If you want the Max value, use

```
=IF(RIGHT(D2,4)=" Mob",MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,LEFT(D2,FIND(" Mob",D2)-1)&"-*"),SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2))
```

[image]

**Edit 2:** If you don't have a modern version of Excel that has MaxIFS(), you can use this approach.

You need a helper column. I inserted column B and used this formula in B2 and copied down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A2)),A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)&" Mob")
```

You can then hide the helper column if it upsets your spreadsheet layout.

Then you can calculate the result with

```
=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$10=E2,$C$2:$C$10))
```

This is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Also, with Array Formulas you don't want to use whole column references. Use ranges that contain only the rows with data, otherwise your spreadsheet will become very slow to recalculate.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Hi teylyn, Needs to return the highest value nut the sum....if you follow the colored cells and the values from manual input you will get the idea. Thanks for trying at least

Comment: Oops. Use Maxifs instead of Sumifs. I updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use maxifs as the excel version is not supporting and I can't update the my office.

Comment: You could have led with that. If you don't use a recent version, please state that in your question, so we don't waste time. I have updated the answer with a solution that works in older versions of Excel.